# The type of (.) map const

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to determine the type of `(.) map const`.

The type of `(.) map` gives me `(a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> [a2] -> [b]`

The type of `const` is `a -> b -> a`

So when I'm trying to do `(.) map const`, shouldn't the `(a1 -> a2 -> b)` of `(.) map` unify with `(a -> b -> a)` from `const`?

Thus, `a1` unifies with `a`, `a2` unifies with `b`, `b` unifies with `a`.
I'm left with `a1 -> [a2] -> b` 
With the unification it should leave me with `a -> [b] -> [a]`

However, the correct answer is `b -> [a] -> [b]`

Can someone explain how and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`a -> [b] -> [a]` and `b -> [a] -> [b]` are the same type (and so is, for example, `foo -> [bar] -> [foo]`). The names of type variables carry no meaning, so as long as the same ones are in the same places, the labels they have don't matter.

Comment: If you want to learn more about this property, it is called _alpha equivalence_.

Answer (score 7):

Answering your comment on @JosephSible's answer, it appears GHCi unification is favoring the type variables from `map`.  This is mere order of operations and arbitrary:

```
map' :: (mapA -> mapB) -> [mapA] -> [mapB]
map' = map

dot :: (dotB -> dotC) -> (dotA -> dotB) -> dotA -> dotC
dot = (.)

const' :: constA -> constB -> constA
const' = const
```

And

```
*Main> :t dot map' const'
dot map' const' :: mapB -> [mapA] -> [mapB]
```